# How to do a safe binary comparison in Python?

Tags: python, unicode

I have the following piece of code that is throwing a warning:

`UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal`

```
try:
    f = open_old(filename, "rb")
    aBuf = f.read(4)
    f.close()
except:
    aBuf=b''
if aBuf[:3] == b'\xEF\xBB\xBF':
    print("...")
```

What is the proper way of reading 3 bytes from the file and checking their values.

I am looking for a solution that would work properly in Python 2.6 and newwer (including 3.x).

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb observation, but wouldn't you want to say `f.read(3)` to read 3 bytes?

Comment: Not quite :) ... this is only an excerpt from a bigger piece of code. Anyway, I already found a solution that works on both Python 2.x and 3.x. Check it at https://github.com/ssbarnea/tendo/blob/master/tendo/unicode.py#L23

Comment: You should add the answer to this thread, then, and accept it.

Comment: The warning is only ever thrown when comparing Python 2 `unicode` objects with a `str` bytestring object. You have *no such comparison* in the sample code here. Your problem cannot stem from the code you posted.

Comment: And what is `open_old` here anyway? That's not a built-in Python function. If that produces a file object that returns `unicode` on Python 2 but `bytes` on Python 3, run away from it. Don't walk, *run*. It is badly broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to convert the string to bytes after you read it: `aBuf = bytes(f.read(4))`.

Comment: I opened a new thread about binary conversion in Python here http://stackoverflow.com/q/31322641/54964 Is your system Linux or Windows? Is your file binary?

Comment: You opened the file in binary mode; that means in Python 3 you *already* get `bytes()`. In Python 2 `bytes` is an alias for `str` and you *already* get `str` objects from `file.read()` call. Using `bytes()` on a file object opened in binary mode **makes no difference whatsoever**.