# Why this binary comparison wrong in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, binary

I am reading this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5950553/54964) but I do not get the binary comparison to work

Code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os

fp = open("/home/masi/r.raw", "rb")

# I think you cannot do binary comparison with seek so read
try:
    aBuf = bytes(fp.read(4))
    while aBuf[:3] != b'\x58\x5E':
        aBuf = bytes(fp.read(4))

except:
    print "File end at position : ", fp.tell()

finally:
    fp.close()
```

getting output in Debian Linux 8.1

```
File end at position :  4
```

Data `r.raw` is binary where first line in hex:

```
48000000fe5a1eda480000000d00030001000000cd010000010000000000
```

so the while loop should be going at least to the position 60. 
The handling of binary by `b'\x..\x..` should be right.

Why is the binary comparison wrong?

Comment: Start by removing the blanket `except`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, Python 2 *doesn't use `bytes()`*. The name `bytes` is an alias for `str()`. `fp.read()` returns `str` objects representing bytes, and the `b` prefix for a string literal is a no-op, it is only there for forward compatibility with Python 3.

Next, you are comparing a slice for 3 characters with a 2 byte string:

```
>>> len('\x58\x5E')
2
>>> len('12345'[:3])
3
```

so the comparison is *never going to be false*.

If you wanted to test the first 2 bytes, use a slice for 2 characters instead:

```
while aBuf[:2] != '\x58\x5E':
```

or use the `str.startswith()` method:

```
while not aBuf.startswith('\x58\x5E'):
```

This doesn't explain your problem, of course, since you'd expect the *whole* file to be read because of this.

However, you are probably getting an `IOError` instead, but you are using *Pokemon exception handling*; you catching em all. Don't use a blanket `except:` statement, you are catching all possible errors including memory errors.

At the very least *log your exceptions*:

```
try:
    aBuf = fp.read(4)
    while aBuf and not aBuf.startswith('\x58\x5E'):
        aBuf = fp.read(4)
except Exception:
    print "File end at position : ", fp.tell()
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
```

I've limited the exceptions being caught to the `Exception` baseclass, to at least not catch memory errors, keyboard interrupts and generator exit exceptions. You really shoud narrow that further down to actual exceptions you want your code to handle (e.g. not *everything*).

Comment: Great answer with thoughtful explanations! Thank you!

Comment: Why did leave out casting to string in reading file like `str(fp.read(4))` but you `fp.read(4)`? Original `bytes(fp.read(4))`. Any harm of using `str`, probably unnecessary in Python 2.7? Why then `bytes` proposed in such a situation in Python 3?

Comment: @Masi: there is no need to cast, as `file.read()` **always** returns a string object. I'm not sure what the other post is about, but the problem stated in the question *doesn't happen with the code posted*. Nor does the answer help in case you do get that error. The answer is, I'm sorry to say, nonsense.